# Is there an Outlook Javascript API to get control to addin on Saving as Draft or before syncing to server?

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I am working on an Outlook addin to make sure confidential information is not leaked using mail.
Using the on-send feature using ItemSend, we were able to get the email fields and block the sendmail, if required
https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-On-Send/tree/master/outlook-add-in-on-send

But there is an use case

1. User composes the mail and saves it to draft (without clicking on Send)
2. In outlook on web, composing a mail saves to draft automatically.

How can the add-in get a callback when draft is synced to Outlook server ?

Comment: There is no callback when a draft is synced. When you eventually send from the client, the On-Send Feature should kick in.

Answer (score 0):

> How can the add-in get a callback when draft is synced to Outlook server ?

There is no such callback available for web add-ins. You may post a feature request or suggest a feature on the [Tech Community](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform) site where community members get to share ideas on ways MS can make Microsoft Graph and Office Platform better by sharing feature requests and ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing like that for the JS-based addins.

For the COM addins, OOM exposes `MailItem.Write` event - your event handler can cancel the operation.